# rpmbuild "Optional dependency" without require

Tags: centos, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I would like to build a RPM Package for a website.
in the `%post` section of my spec file I would like to check if the apache webserver is installed. If so, the config should be copied to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`

If no Apache is installed, the config should just be stored in the projectfolder and the admin has to configure the webserver on his own.

So I need a construct like

```
if [Apache installed]
  cp [configfile] /etc/httpd/conf.d/
```

**EDIT**
I found out, I maybe could use `rpm -q httpd` for it. But how can I use it in the `%post` section?

Answer (score 0):

`(rpm -q --quiet httpd && cp yourfile /etc/httpd/conf.d/) || true`

This will copy your config file over.

Of course, an easier way might just be

`( [ -d /etc/httpd/conf.d ] && cp yourfile /etc/httpd/conf.d/) || true`

Which says if the directory exists, drop it there, regardless of why the directory is there.

The extra "`|| true` " at the end causes the result of the line to always be OK so `rpm` won't claim a scriptlet failed if it didn't exist.

Here's how I tested it:

```
[user@Niflheim ~]# rpm -q --quiet httpds && echo Yep
[user@Niflheim ~]# echo $?
1
[user@Niflheim ~]# # Need to move to subshell...
[user@Niflheim ~]# (rpm -q --quiet httpds && echo Yep) || true
[user@Niflheim ~]# echo $?
0
[user@Niflheim ~]# (rpm -q --quiet httpd && echo Yep) || true
Yep
[user@Niflheim ~]# echo $?
0
[user@Niflheim ~]#
```

There are probably some macros you should be using instead of hardcoding `/etc/`, but I'm on my way out the door.